# CollectionViewCell Fixed size as Apple News app

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I tried to make my app look like apple news app.

I did limitation of numberOfItemsPerRow cause I don't know how to make it changes to fits iPad size or whatever the device sizes?

The question how to make it fit any ios device(iPhone and the iPad) not only three items/row also the height/Looks isn't good enough.

I hope someone help.

```
private let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 32.0
private let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 3.0
private let heigthAdjustment: CGFloat = 20.0

// MARK: - View controller life cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let width = (CGRectGetWidth(collectionView!.frame) - leftAndRightPaddings) / numberOfItemsPerRow
    let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, width + heigthAdjustment)

}
```

cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
    // Configure the cell
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to look exactly like the news app, you can measure the cells in photoshop and get a sense for the point width and height and set the cell's height and width in your storyboard.

If you need to change the size programmatically and what want to give a size for specific type of device, you should use UITraitCollection. You can say something like:

```
if self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Regular{
    //set or return size for iPad
}
```

For more information about UITraitCollection and size classes you can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@UIUserInterfaceSizeClass)